# How to display NEXT action items followed by TODO items in Agenda View

Tags: org-mode

I want to configure a custom agenda view which displays NEXT items followed by TODO items. currently all the TODO items and NEXT items are mixed in the agenda view.

After going through the manual i came across the variable

```
org-agenda-custom-commands
```

which seems to do the job, but it seems like it can act on single TODO state of an item. How to configure the agend view to display NEXT items followed by TODO items.

Comment: Do you want something like: All `NEXT` then all `TODO` or ar `NEXT` somehow associated with `TODO` and you want to display them together?

Comment: I did not understood the second part of your question(NEXT somehow associated with TODO and you want to display them together?) but The first part of the question is what i want to do.

Comment: I was hinting at some relationship between a `NEXT` and a `TODO` tag. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `org-agend-sorting-strategy`. Possibly `todo-state-up` should do the trick when `NEXT` is defined as a custom keyword, but I don't know that for sure. Otherwise a user-defined sort should do the trick.

This snippet from worg should be clearer:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands 
      '(
      ("c" "Desk Work" tags-todo "" ;; (1) (2) (3) (4)
           ((org-agenda-files '("~/org/widgets.org" "~/org/clients.org")) ;; leave blank for configured default
           (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(todo-state-down))) ;; fiddle with the setting here
         )
        ;; ...other commands here
        ))
```

Comment: you are right, the sorting strategy should be "todo-state-down"

Comment: @Talespin_Kit Fixed for the sake of completeness.